# Change the value of a variable after it's been set

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

here's my problem.

I have this piece of code that sets the user location as coordinates in a textbox.

```
var initialLocation;           
$('#from').val(initialLocation);
```

The initialLocation variable gets the user current location as coordinates and then `$('#from').val(initialLocation);` puts those coordinates in the textbox "from".

But instead of boring coordinates like "45.542307, -73.567200"  I'd like my textbox to simply show "Your location".

So basically, I want to have the coordinates in my textbox, but change what the user sees from "45.542307, -73.567200" to "Your location".

Is it possible to do such a thing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data method of Jquery which stores data specific to the element

```
    $("#from").data("currentLocation", initialLocation).val("Your location");

//To retrieve the currentLocation
$("#from").data("currentLocation");
```

Comment: Note that if you are submitting this form to the back-end, the value "Your location" will be passed and not the coordinates stored in data.  If you are just manipulating this data with javascript and not submitting the form directly then this should work.

Comment: Yes that is true, you have us $("#from").data("currentLocation") to get the actual value.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just have 2 text boxes, one that is hidden and has the real value and another which is visible which you put "Current Location" into.